# A time series which doesn't look stationary but pass the ADF (augmented Dicky-Fuller) test

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

My time series look like this, but it passed the ADF test. Does it make any sense?

[image]

Comment: Which variant of the ADF test did you run (the one with trend I would assume?)